# sysext:form How to include StaticText in email finisher?

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I would like to include the content of the StaticText elements in the confirmation email, because it is legally relevant and should be printed.

How to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Element can be re-enabled via Yaml-Configuration:

```
TYPO3:
  CMS:
    Form:
      prototypes:
        standard:
          formElementsDefinition:
            StaticText:
              variants: null
```

This already outputs the header. To output the text, we need `{formValue.element.properties.text}` in the Fluid-Template (Plaintext.html or Html.html).

The Fluid-Template also needs to be enabled via Yaml:

```
TYPO3:
  CMS:
    Form:
      prototypes:
        standard:
          finishersDefinition:
            EmailToReceiver:
              options:
                templateRootPaths:
                  20: 'EXT:user_site/Resources/Private/Templates/Extensions/form/Templates/Finishers/Email/'
```